# Accessing Shared Folder Using Oracle Database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, remote, archive

I have two machines A & B. I shared a folder from machine B and mapped it as a drive on machine A. Now I want to configure my Oracle Database in Archive Log mode and want to set the Archive location to that mapped drive. I have also set full (Read/Write) permissions to that folder. But for testing purpose I tried to create a file on that folder through SQL as:

`SQL> CREATE pfile='z:\archive\pfile.ora' FROM spfile;`

It says:

`ERROR at line 1:`
`ORA-09210: sftopn: error opening file`
`OSD-04002: unable to open file`
`O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.`

How can I make this drive available for Oracle Database?

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 1):

**To troubleshoot this type of erro follow the steps bellow :**

- 1- make sure that the location where you want to write exists.
- 2- make sure that the oracle(or the user who runs the database instance) user has the right to write in that
  location.(try to create txt file in that location as Oracle user.)

Ok , more steps for you to troubleshoot:
- i see you are running Oracle on Windowzzz! Correct ?
 Go to your Services tool and see who(what account) is running the Oracle services, form here make sure this user has access to the directory where you what to write to!

Now maybe is better for you to write into another location(your user home directory):

```
SQL> CREATE pfile='C:\Users\user.name\Downloads\pfile' FROM spfile;
```

- if the error persists then your problem is different ! 
  From this point you can think of security baselines etc...

Comment: 1- The location exists on the system and I created some folders and files within that folder on operating system level by logging as an Administrator that is only user in my OS.

Comment: 2- I have installed oracle software as an OS user Administrator. And login into database as a user sys. That user resides within the database not on operating System level.

Comment: You are wrong with your assumptions. There are a lot of articles that say that mapped drives will not work with sercvices , eg http://serverfault.com/questions/4623/windows-can-i-map-a-network-drive-for-a-service-account

Answer (score 1):

- **use the [Uniform Naming Convention (UNC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention)** "\\machine_name\share_name\path"
- **run the Oracle windows services using a [Domain User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has granted FULL CONTROL  to the network drive**  and not the  "Local System Account" that is used by default. This should be done especially to the windows services "OracleService..." and the "Oracle...TNSListener" for this database. A windows service is modified by opening the windows service in the control panel and entry an appropriate account in "Startup"/"Logon as:" .  The account that runs the Oracle windows services should be member of  "ora_dba" and maybe of "Administrator"

These hints are from Metalink note [Running UTL_FILE on Windows NT (Doc ID 45172.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=45172.1) but I think they are valid for other files accessed by Oracle, too,. Similar hints can be found in [Unable To Export To A Mapped Network Drive Using DataPump (Doc ID 428130.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=428130.1), [How to Configure RMAN to Write to Shared Drives on Windows NT/2000/2003 (Doc ID 145843.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=145843.1), [RMAN Backup On Remote Machine Disk On Windows (Doc ID 729664.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=729664.1)

**Additional notes:**
  1. Maybe the account on that  runs Oracle and the account on the other machine that shares the drives should be "Administrator" accounts and have the same password (if they are local accounts) or should be a Domain Administrator account (this is described [Doc ID 145843.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=145843.1) and [Doc ID 729664.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=729664.1))
  2. From the cited metalink note I conclude  that if one uses mapped drives the  user that has created that mapped drives must be logged on that  the service can use the mapped drives. This would explain your error message.So it is better to use UNC drives instead of mapped drives.
  3. Maybe there are some security riscs if you use this setup (e.g. if you use a Domain Admin account for Oracle)